# Cannot install libgstreamer-0.10

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, libraries, aptitude

I' using Debian 9
Cannot install libgstreamer-0.10.so
I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer0.10-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer0.10-0'
```

When I search

```
sudo apt-cache search libgstreamer
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 - GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev - GStreamer development files for libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer1.0-0 - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgstreamer1.0-dev - GStreamer core development files
libgstreamermm-1.0-1 - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (shared libraries)
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (development files)
libgstreamermm-1.0-doc - C++ wrapper library for GStreamer (documentation)
libgstreamer-ocaml - OCaml interface to the gstreamer library -- runtime files
libgstreamer-ocaml-dev - OCaml interface to the gstreamer library -- development files
libgstreamerd-3-0 - GStreamer media framework - D bindings
libgstreamerd-3-0-dbgsym - Debug symbols for libgstreamerd-3-0
libgstreamerd-3-dev - GStreamer media framework - development files for D
```

I created a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

and

/etc/apt/preferences.d/unstable

```
    Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

But when I run apt-cache policy libgstreamer0.10-0
I get same error

```
apt-cache policy libgstreamer0.10-0
```

After I typed apt-get update

```
    sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease                       
Ign:3 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian stretch InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease          
Hit:6 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian stretch Release                    
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: @maulinglawns I' getting error when type apt-cache policy libgstreamer0.10-0 N: Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-0
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgstreamer0.10-0'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgstreamer0.10-0'

Comment: after I done steps with /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list and /etc/apt/preferences.d/unstable

Comment: I don't have Debian running so I don't know for sure (suggestion, not an 'answer in a comment') but I think that 0.10 was removed. See [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043413/problem-with-libgstreamer0-10-when-trying-to-install-some-software). You can include "OldStable" in your sources list (so you can apt-get it, and figure out how to resolve conflicts) or get the file [manually](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgstreamer0.10-0).

Comment: Don't specify the version number. Just input: sudo apt-get install libgstreamer